# which query to be used in data base

Tags: python, django, sqlite

For the quiz app, I am having the following model

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
  question_text=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text


class Options(models.Model):
  question=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  options=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  is_answer=models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.options
```

Only one option for each question is Set to True. I need to find the option of the question which is having the `is_answer` field is set to True.  Which is the best query here? I am using Sqlite. Thank You.

Comment: ... and the query should return what?

Comment: @dhke updated ,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
# Get a Question instance. Your implementation may be different. 
question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_pk)
correct_option = question.options_set.filter(is_answer=True).first()
```

Doing `question.options_set.filter(is_answer=True)` returns a queryset of `Options` instances that have a FK to the `question` instance so doing `.first()` returns the first instance in the queryset.

You can also `get` a particular option (given "Only one option for each question is Set to True"):

```
try:    
    question.options_set.get(is_answer=True)
except Options.DoesNotExist:
    raise
```

Comment: ... given the assertion that only one option is only ever true for each question, `.get(is_answer=True)` might be even better, since it fails when the invariance is violated (catch errors early ...)

Comment: @dhke that's right. But I'd imagine he has a validation at the model layer to avoid creating more than one option with `is_answer=True` for a particular question.